# Use list as Clojure function body

Tags: list, function, clojure, symbols

let's say that in Clojure I have a list defined like this:

```
(def function-body '(+ a b))
```

Next I would like to use the `function-body` list as the effective body of a function, so I would like to do something like:

```
(defn my-sum [a b] function-body)
```

to produce:

```
(defn my-sum [a b] (+ a b))
```

Which is valid Clojure code.

Is this possible in Clojure? If I should revert to macro, what kind of expansion should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to use a macro for this.  The code as you have it would just return the list `'(+ a b)`, not do any addition.

On another note what problem are you actually trying to solve?  I don't really see why you would want to do something like this.  You might be asking the wrong question.

Comment: I'm trying to decouple building of function body and function declaration. But I understand that maybe the simplest approach is to wrap the list in a fn declaration and eval the complete declaration. What do you think about this?

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to decouple the building of a function body and a function declaration.

Comment: Because the idea here was to generate the bodies from another data structure (i.e. a map) and maybe to manipulate them, and then wrap them in a function declaration. I wanted to not use eval in the end, although I understand that macro and eval give me the power to do everything I want...

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio  So you are generating a function from a map. Is this process regular enough to be captured as a function? If so, the map is a parametric structure for the function, and you don't even need a macro: a function-generating function will do.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you need to keep the function body as a form. The function itself, `(fn [a b] (+ a b))` in your example, is available as a thing you can pass as an argument, employ as an element in a data structure, as well as doing the function thing of calling upon arguments.

Your purpose is probably to have several functions available that you might call, according to circumstances. Keep them as functions, not as forms.

Answer (score 1):

```
(def function-body '(+ a b))
(eval `(defn ~'my-sum ~'[a b] ~function-body))
```

Quick explanation:

```
; what we eval above is this:
`(defn ~'my-sum ~'[a b] ~function-body)
; which becomes this:
; (clojure.core/defn my-sum [a b] (+ a b))
(my-sum 2 3) ; => 5
```

A macro would be very similar, i.e. just unquote the body.

Comment: Yes, in the end Eval is your only friend for easy dynamic code loading :)